# Custom DeviceInformation PairAsync gives RequiredHandlerNotRegistered result

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a WPF application to communicate with a BLE enabled device. I am using the PairAsync function from **Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformationCustomPairing** class, but I have noticed some strange behavior.

My application first detects whether the device is already paired, if not then it tries to pair with the device. I'm using custom pairing to let the UI prompt the user for the PIN. I provide that pin in args.Accept() of the custom pairing handler (OnPair function).

```
private async Task PairingAsync(DeviceInformation devInfo)
        {
            var pairingInformation = devInfo.Pairing;
            if (pairingInformation.CanPair)
            {
                pairingInformation.Custom.PairingRequested += this.OnPair;
                var result = await pairingInformation.Custom.PairAsync(DevicePairingKinds.ProvidePin, DevicePairingProtectionLevel.None);
                pairingInformation.Custom.PairingRequested -= this.OnPair;

                if (result.Status == DevicePairingResultStatus.Paired ||
                    result.Status == DevicePairingResultStatus.AlreadyPaired)
                    Logger.Info("Device is paired successfully");
                else
                {
                    Logger.Info($"Error occured while pairing with device: {result.Status.ToString()}");
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Pairing with device is not under control, connecting cancelled.\n Try to pair manually");
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Pairing with device is forbidden");
            }
        }
```

```
private void OnPair(DeviceInformationCustomPairing sender, DevicePairingRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            Logger.Info("Pairing requested...");
            switch (args.PairingKind)
            {
                case DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmOnly:
                    // Windows itself will pop the confirmation dialog as part of "consent" if this is running on Desktop or Mobile
                    // If this is an App for 'Windows IoT Core' or a Desktop and Console application
                    // where there is no Windows Consent UX, you may want to provide your own confirmation.
                    args.Accept();
                    break;

                case DevicePairingKinds.ProvidePin:
                    // A PIN may be shown on the target device and the user needs to enter the matching PIN on 
                    // this Windows device. Get a deferral so we can perform the async request to the user.
                    args.Accept(this.pin);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

The first time I select the device to pair, I get result.Status = **RequiredHandlerNotRegistered**. At the same time, the System (Windows) dialog for pairing with the device pops up. Since I am custom pairing, the system dialog shouldn't appear. When I close the system dialog and try selecting the device to pair again in my application, it pairs successfully with result.Status = **Paired**

I still don't fully understand why this works the second time and not the first. What is the RequiredHandlerNotRegistered status and why does it occur when I try to pair with the device for the first time? I went over the documentation and this status can occur when either the handler isn't registered (I have a custom handler), or when the DevicePairingKind is not supporter (ProvidePin is supported by the device, also pairing works in the second attempt)